# half day check-in with BETWEEN command

Tags: php, mysql, date-range

I want to to pick an interval from this records, with this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `table` 
WHERE camera_id =  '4' 
    AND data  BETWEEN  '2015-03-29 12:00:01' AND  '2015-03-30 11:59:59'
```

the problem is that, for the intervals from 1 day, eg from 03-29 to 03-30 does not find the record, and for several days working as 03-29 to 03-31

What do I need? NOT find a range of dates to be included in those times to book a room. so if I record with the same `prenotazione_id` must give me back empty. if I know that I need a foreach.
[image]

Comment: what is datatype of your table column data?

Comment: I used your query in my table its working fine with datetime datatype of column

Comment: @Pankajkatiyar see the comment below

Comment: Can you post the expected results you want to get? Your question and explanations are unclear, *grazie* ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your BETWEEN skips one second -- Noon.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM  `table` WHERE camera_id = '4' AND data BETWEEN 
DATE_FORMAT('2015-03-29 12:00:01','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') 
 AND 
DATE_FORMAT('2015-03-29 12:00:01','%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') AS date
```